# Two threads sharing the static boolean field, but still the first thread don't exit

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

What I am trying to achieve is, creating 2 threads sharing a common static boolean resource so that depending on the flag values the first thread should exit, but still the first thread runs.

This is the code below,

```
     class SharedResource08{    

        public synchronized void doIt() throws Exception{

            while(!SharedResource07.getBFlag()){
                System.out.println(" THE THREAD "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Thread.sleep(250);
            }   
        }

     }

     class SharedResource07{
        private static boolean bFLag = false;

        public static synchronized void setBFlag(boolean bFLag){        
            bFLag = bFLag;      
            System.out.println(" THREAD "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" setting value bFLag := "+bFLag);
        }

        public static  boolean getBFlag(){
            return bFLag;
        }   

     }


     class MyThread07 extends Thread{

        private SharedResource08  resource;

        MyThread07(String threadName,SharedResource08 resource){
        super(threadName);
            this.resource = resource;
        }

        public  void run(){
            try{

                if(getName().equals("JACK")){
                    resource.doIt();
                }else if(getName().equals("JILL")){
                    SharedResource07.setBFlag(true);
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
     }


     public class Ex07{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            SharedResource08 resource = new SharedResource08();
            MyThread07 t1 = new MyThread07("JACK",resource);
            MyThread07 t2 = new MyThread07("JILL",resource);
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }   
     }
```

What I am expecting is, thread t1 will execute the doit() method of class SharedResource08,
in the meantime the second thread t2 should set the flag bFLag of class SharedResource07 to true, now once this flag is true, the thread t1 should exit the method doIt(),

but this doesn't happen, my thread t1 goes on printing the SOP.
Need some suggestion.

Comment: Mark the boolean field as volatile.

Comment: @Mauricio: you should add your comment as an answer (it's the solution, isn't it?)

Comment: You need to be synchronizing on the same object. When SharedResource08.doIt() calls getBFlag() it doesn't hold a lock on that object.  Instead it hold a lock on itself which doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a typical mistake:

Change this:

```
public static synchronized void setBFlag(boolean bFLag){        
        bFLag = bFLag; // assigning the parameter to the parameter
```

for this:

```
public static synchronized void setBFlag(boolean bFLag){        
        SharedResource07.bFLag = bFLag;  // assigning the parameter to the static field
```

Some IDEs are good at avoiding this kind of errors by signaling warnings on code. Always keep an Eclipse at hand :)

Comment: Except you can't do that, as `bFlag` is a static field. Solution: the parameter should be called something else.

Comment: Yep, I've changed ir for `SharedResource07.bFLag`

Comment: above said change gives an error "Ex07.java:19: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @RahulShivsharan - helios has updated the code, try the new version

Comment: One more thing @Rahul: if you are guarding access to a field (as in `setBFlag`) you must guard *all* accesses to it to be effective, so `getBFlag` must be `syncrhonized` too.

Comment: bFlag is class member, not object member, so can't using this keyword.

Comment: I'll change redaction. I didn't want to be offensive :)

Comment: the method getBFlag method just gets the boolean value it do not updated any flag hence i didn't made it synchronized. One more thing, why do bFlag need to be volatile, as its a static field, its not the part ofobject, so no local copy is created, so why volatile ?, can you please help me out on this

Comment: volatile: I'm not very strong on this point, you should look for documentation on volatile keyword. It has to do with local copies of the value for a given thread (so it doesn't check the real value). sync'ing getters: It's the way to ensure that nobody is reading the value while other thread is writing at it (if you're reading something less atomic it can happen you read part old and part new value). By example reading name and last name: T1 reads name / T2 modifies last-name / T1 reads last-name. T1 got mixed information.

Answer (score 2):

Each thread can make its own local copy of any field that isn't declared `volatile`, unless access is protected by a `synchronized` block.

In your case the easiest option is to add the `volatile` keyword to your boolean field, as any updates to it will be atomic anyway (it being a single boolean value). In more complex cases advanced synchronization is needed.

Concurrency is quite a big and heavy subject in general, but [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) might help starting to tackle it.

Comment: adding volatile didn't worked, still t1 didn't stopped, any other suggestion

Comment: Yes, because there's another error in the code: as @helios pointed out, you're not actually setting the field.

Comment: @helios It will be though, once the first problem is fixed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well u got a right answer From our friend helios.
the problem u were facing was the Jill thread is not actually modifying SharedResource07 class bFlag.either u rename your formal parameter or put

```
 SharedResource07.bFlag=bFlag;
```

Adding volatile to static member does two thing.
1) value of variable is never shared to threads local resource.it will be stored in main memory.
2)access to that variable is synchronized.

Comment: but bFlag = bFLag and SharedResource07.bFlag = bFLag, is one and the same, right ? the blFlag was refered in the same class hence i didn't used the SharedREsource07.bFlag.  Can you please put some light in this

Comment: since bFlag is static member of class we have to refer it via classname since it does not have **this** associated with it so by writing bFlag = bFLag we are creating ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

> What i am expecting is, thread t1 will execute the doit() method of class SharedResource08

Its not ensured tht your doIt() method ever runs. It may arise that "JILL" thread gets the scheduled tiem earlier goes in to else part and set the respource flag. a `race condition`

just wanted to point out beside all the things pointed out in other code.

Beside all we are pointing to `volatile` which is right thing to be used.

you can do it with `Atomicboolean` too. Have a look at the same. A new alternative approach to synchronized paradigm